# Simplify/Evaluate $y = x + a \frac{dx}{dt}$

Tags: calculus

I have the following equation which I am totally unable to solve.

$$y = x + v$$ $$v = a \frac{dx}{dt}$$ $$ y = x + a \frac{dx}{dt}$$

Nothing is a constant and everything is somehow related to another, I need to find the realtion between $y$ and $x$

The problem originated from here : 
$$Q_1 = Q_2 + Q_3$$ $$\frac{Q_2}{C_2} = R_2 \frac{dQ_3}{dt}$$
here I need to find a relation between $Q_1$ and $Q_2$, also as $Q_1$, $Q_2$ & $Q_3$ are changes in different branches of a circuit all are dependent on each other and have a dependency on time which I am calculating.

Comment: Have you tried to solve the differential equation? Assuming $a \ne 0$: $\frac{dx}{dt} - \frac{x}{a} = \frac{y}{a} \Leftrightarrow \frac{d}{dt} (xe^{\frac{1}{a} t}) = \frac{y}{a} e^{\frac{1}{a} t} \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{1}{a} e^{- \frac{1}{a} t} \int {y{e^{\frac{1}{a}t}}} dt + Ce^{- \frac{1}{a} t}$

Answer (score 0):

We can assume that Q(1) can be known in advance as a differentiable function of time t.So the system gives: d/dt(Q(3)) + L*Q(3) = L*Q(1) whereas L = 1/(R(2)*C(2)). So you have a 1st order ODE in Q(3). The multiplier is u = e^(Lt). So you have: d/dt(e^(Lt)*Q(3)) = L*e^(Lt)*Q(1). So integrate both sides: e^(Lt)*Q(3) = L*Integral(t = 0 to T)(Q(1)*e^(Lt)) and solve for Q(3): Q(3) = e^(-Lt)*Integral(t = 0 to T)(Q(1)*e^(Lt)). And Q(2) = L*d/dt(Q(3) which can then be calculated in term of Q(1) through differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are solving RC charging equation. The easiest way to solve this is to do it in two steps. If you do know $y(t)$ then you can simplify the second step.

Solve for $y=0$:
$$
0 = x + a \frac{dx}{dt}$$
The solution is $$
x(t) = C e^{-t/a}$$
where $C$ is a constant.

To solve the general case, you write
$$
x(t) = C(t) e^{-t/a}$$
where $C(t)$ is *no longer a constant*
Substituting in the equation you get
$$y(t) = C(t) e^{-t/a} + a \left(\frac{C(t)}{dt} e^{-t/a} + C(t) \frac{e^{-t/a}}{dt}\right) = a \frac{C(t)}{dt} e^{-t/a} $$

Hence
$$
C(t) = C(0) + \frac{1}{a} \int_0^t y(\tau) e^{\tau/a} d \tau$$
Clearly $C(0) = x(0)$. Hence
$$
x(t) = C(t) e^{-t/a} = x(0) e^{-t/a} + \frac{1}{a} e^{-t/a}\int_0^t y(\tau) e^{\tau/a} d \tau$$

If you know about convolution integrals, you will recognize the integral as the convolution integral from linear systems.

**Added in response to comments**

$\tau$ is just the dummy variable. You may be more familiar with the integral in the form
$$
\int_0^t y(t) e^{t/a} d t
$$
Mathematically the $t$ in the limit is not the same as the $t$ inside the integral but this abuse of notation is not uncommon.

Comment: I think it is stuck at the end again as I do not know the definition for $y(\tau) $ ! Any ideas ?